# Android AltBeacon background and foreground together

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, beacon, altbeacon

Good day. In my application i want to use background and foreground beacons scan. For this task i used AltBeacon library. But after device reboot background scan not starts.

My algorith looks like:

- When application started, start monitor and attach lifecycle listener
  for detect when activity dies.
- When activity dies - start background scan.
- When activity goes back to front - stop backgroun and run foreground.

What i have now:

At first - foreground "service" (not really service, just class)

```
class BeaconForegroundService(private val application: Application) : BeaconConsumer {

private var beaconManager: BeaconManager? = null

companion object {
    private const val REGION_UID = "region_uid"
}

override fun getApplicationContext(): Context {
    return application.applicationContext
}

override fun unbindService(p0: ServiceConnection) {
    application.unbindService(p0)
}

override fun bindService(p0: Intent, p1: ServiceConnection, p2: Int): Boolean {
    return application.bindService(p0, p1, p2)
}

override fun onBeaconServiceConnect() {

    beaconManager!!.beaconParsers.clear()
    beaconManager!!.beaconParsers.add(AltBeaconParser())
    beaconManager!!.beaconParsers.add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.URI_BEACON_LAYOUT))
    beaconManager!!.beaconParsers.add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_TLM_LAYOUT))
    beaconManager!!.beaconParsers.add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT))
    beaconManager!!.beaconParsers.add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_URL_LAYOUT))
    beaconManager!!.beaconParsers.add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"))
    beaconManager!!.backgroundMode = false

    beaconManager!!.addMonitorNotifier(object : MonitorNotifier {
        override fun didDetermineStateForRegion(p0: Int, p1: Region?) {
            Timber.d("FGBeacon: didDetermineStateForRegion INSIDE = ${p0 == MonitorNotifier.INSIDE}")
        }

        override fun didEnterRegion(p0: Region?) {
            Timber.d("FGBeacon: didEnterRegion")
        }

        override fun didExitRegion(p0: Region?) {
            Timber.d("FGBeacon: didExitRegion")
        }
    })
    beaconManager!!.addRangeNotifier { mutableCollection: MutableCollection<Beacon>, region: Region ->
        Timber.d("FGBeacon $mutableCollection")
    }
    beaconManager!!.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(Region(REGION_UID, null, null, null))
    beaconManager!!.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(Region(REGION_UID, null, null, null))
}

fun startScan() {
    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(application)
    beaconManager!!.bind(this)
}

fun stopScan() {
    beaconManager?.unbind(this)
}
```

}

Background scan inside application class:

```
class MyApplication : Application(), BootstrapNotifier {

// Fields
private var beaconManager: BeaconManager? = null
private var backgroundPowerSaver: BackgroundPowerSaver ?= null
private var regionBootstrap : RegionBootstrap ?= null
private var foregroundService: BeaconForegroundService ?= null
val REGION_UID = "region_uid"

//Method for start background scan here

fun startScan() {
        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this)
        beaconManager!!.beaconParsers.clear()
        beaconManager!!.beaconParsers.add(AltBeaconParser())
        beaconManager!!.beaconParsers.add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.URI_BEACON_LAYOUT))
        beaconManager!!.beaconParsers.add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_TLM_LAYOUT))
        beaconManager!!.beaconParsers.add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT))
        beaconManager!!.beaconParsers.add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_URL_LAYOUT))
        beaconManager!!.beaconParsers.add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"))

        val notificationBuilder = Notification.Builder(this)
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Scanning for beacons")
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, MainActivity.BEACON_REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel("MyChannelId", "NotyName", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
            channel.description = "NotyDesc"
            val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
            notificationBuilder.setChannelId(channel.id)
        }




        val region = Region(REGION_UID, null, null, null)

        beaconManager!!.enableForegroundServiceScanning(notificationBuilder.build(), 456)
        beaconManager!!.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false)
        beaconManager!!.backgroundBetweenScanPeriod = 0
        beaconManager!!.backgroundScanPeriod = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5)
        beaconManager!!.backgroundMode = true

        regionBootstrap  = RegionBootstrap(this, region)
        backgroundPowerSaver = BackgroundPowerSaver(this)

        beaconManager!!.addRangeNotifier { mutableCollection: MutableCollection<Beacon>, r: Region ->
            Timber.d("PBeacon $mutableCollection")
        }
    }

//Disable background scan if application start in foreground
fun disableMonitoring() {
        regionBootstrap?.disable()
        regionBootstrap = null
        beaconManager?.removeAllRangeNotifiers()
    }

  override fun didDetermineStateForRegion(p0: Int, p1: Region?) {
        Timber.d("PBeacon: StateForRegion INSIDE = ${p0 == MonitorNotifier.INSIDE}")
    }

//Start ranging if we inside region
    override fun didEnterRegion(p0: Region?) {
        Timber.d("PBeacon: I see a beacon first time")
        beaconManager!!.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(Region(REGION_UID, null, null, null))

    }

//Stop ranging if we move out from region
    override fun didExitRegion(p0: Region?) {
        Timber.d("PBeacon : I no longer see a beacon.")
        beaconManager!!.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(Region(REGION_UID, null, null, null))
    }
```

And finally - registered listener for detect foreground/background app state changes (inside onCreate of application)

```
registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(object : ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

            //Stop background scan and start foreground
            override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity?) {
                disableMonitoring() 

                foregroundService = BeaconForegroundService(this@MyApplication)
                foregroundService!!.startScan()
            }

              //Stop foreground scan and start background
              override fun onActivityStopped(activity: Activity?) {
                foregroundService?.stopScan()
                foregroundService = null

                startScan()
            }

        })
```

**Logs here:**

Logs when application starting in foreground (looks fine)

```
D/BeaconParser: Parsing beacon layout: m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25
D/BeaconParser: Parsing beacon layout: m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25
D/BeaconParser: Parsing beacon layout: s:0-1=fed8,m:2-2=00,p:3-3:-41,i:4-21v
D/BeaconParser: Parsing beacon layout: x,s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=20,d:3-3,d:4-5,d:6-7,d:8-11,d:12-15
D/BeaconParser: Parsing beacon layout: s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=00,p:3-3:-41,i:4-13,i:14-19
D/BeaconParser: Parsing beacon layout: s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=10,p:3-3:-41,i:4-21v
D/BeaconParser: Parsing beacon layout: m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25
....
BeaconForegroundService$onBeaconServiceConnect: [id1: b5b182c7-eab1-4988-aa99-b5c1517008d9 id2: 1 id3: 57197]
```

Close app (background mode?):

```
Processing pdu type FF: 0201061aff4c000215b5b182c7eab14988aa99b5c1517008d90001df6dc50d0961626561636f6e5f36444446000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 29
D/BeaconParser: This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. Was expecting aa fe at offset 5 and 20 at offset 7.  The bytes I see are: 0201061aff4c000215b5b182c7eab14988aa99b5c1517008d90001df6dc50d0961626561636f6e5f36444446000000000000000000000000000000000000
 D/BeaconParser: Ignoring pdu type 01
...
 D/BeaconParser: Processing pdu type FF: 0201061aff4c000215b5b182c7eab14988aa99b5c1517008d90001df6dc50d0961626561636f6e5f36444446000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 29
D/BeaconParser: This is a recognized beacon advertisement -- 02 15 seen
D/BeaconParser: Bytes are: 0201061aff4c000215b5b182c7eab14988aa99b5c1517008d90001df6dc50d0961626561636f6e5f36444446000000000000000000000000000000000000
D/ScanHelper: Beacon packet detected for: id1: b5b182c7-eab1-4988-aa99-b5c1517008d9 id2: 1 id3: 57197 with rssi -46
D/RangeState: adding id1: b5b182c7-eab1-4988-aa99-b5c1517008d9 id2: 1 id3: 57197 to existing range for: org.altbeacon.beacon.service.RangedBeacon@332c859
```

After reboot:

```
I/BeaconManager: BeaconManager started up on pid 7407 named 'com.myapp' for application package 'com.myapp'.  isMainProcess=true
D/BeaconParser: Parsing beacon layout: m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25
```

And that's all. No detections, waiting (20+ minutes)

So

1. Is it bug of library/device or i doing something wrong?
2. Can we use background scan without notification?
3. Whan we start application again (to foreground) notification refreshed. How can i avoid this?

Big thanks

Comment: Try moving the startRanginfBeaconsInRegion() call inside the didDetermineStateForRegion method.  After restart, the region state is persisted, so you will not get a new call to didEnterRegion if you were already inside when the app last was running.  The didDetermineState callback is always made on restart so it is a good place to trigger starting ranging..

Comment: Also, make sure the startScan() call is triggered in the Application class' onCreate method, and verify by debug lines that it gets called.

Comment: If you are using Android 8+, make sure you have library version 2.15.2 or higher (the version shows up in the logs) otherwise starting a foreground service in the background won't work.  See: https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/pull/746

Comment: @davidgyoung Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, not working. Lib version - 2.15.2
onCreate of application not called. I move startRangingBeaconsInRegion inside didDetermineStateForRegion callback method, but after reboot still not started.

Comment: @davidgyoung So i took code from example (https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beaconreference/BeaconReferenceApplication.java) and now scanner work after reboot! But no beacons found :(
I see that didDetermineStateForRegion always has first arg = 0, it's "OUTSIDE". 
D/BeaconService: Currently monitoring 1 regions.
I/BeaconService: stop ranging received
D/BeaconService: Currently ranging 0 regions.

Comment: If you are running the reference app be sure to add the beaconParser for iBeacon.  The reference app only detects AltBeacon as built.  To your other comment, if you do not see onCreate get called in your Application class, you need to resolve that first.  Make sure your Application class is registered in your AndroidManifest.xml